# boost::asio async_accept always occur a error, error_code.value() is 22, which means invalid argument

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have use boost::asio, there are 8 threads

```
boost::asio::io_service ios;


boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(ios);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port);
acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
acceptor.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
acceptor.listen();

LocalTcpServer::getInstance()->initialize(ios, acceptor, pool);

boost::thread_group th_group;
for(i=0; i< 8; i++)
th_group.add_thread(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ios)));
th_group.join_all();





session::start()
{
    socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), m_strand.wrap(boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)))
}
session::handleread(boost::system::error_code &e, size_t byteTrans)
{
    if(e || byteTrans == 0 )
    {
         socket.shutdown(...)
         //socketRelease close the socket and delete this
         timeInfo->timer->async_wait(boost::bind(socketRelease(), ...);
    }
    else
    {
       //deal with data whit pool;  
    }

    socket.async_read_some(.....);
}









LocaltcpServer::initialize(ios, acceptor, pool){ 
   //init, pool is inherit from threadpool, used in handle read to deal with     receive data
   ...; 
   startaccept(); 
}
LocalTcpServer::Accept()
{
     session* pSession = new session(acceptor->get_io_service, pool);
     acceptor.async_accept(session->socket, boost::bind(handle_accept, this, pSession, boost::asio::placeholder::error))
}

LocalTcpServer::handle_accept(boost::system::error_code& e; ... );
{
    if(e)
    {
        //when app run sometime(serveral hours or days, e has always error 22, means invalid argument )
        LOG_ERROR << e.message() << e.value();
        delete newSession;
        accept();
    }
    else
    {
         session.start();
         accept();
    }
}
```

the app is work fine at first, but some times later, may serveral hours, 1 or two days later , the error comes , hander_accpte always get an err, invalid argument.  so , there is no new connect,

the socket connect is almost 10000, and file open limit is 65535, 
and I have use netstat to check that the socket is closed normally, there is no socket whitout closed
I wonder why the err occured, and how can I fixed it,
or if my code has some errors?
I wish that I describe the question clear. thanks.

Comment: does `m_strand.wrap()` wraps your callback inside a thread?  For some reason, 8 threads sounds like a lot for a library that can handle 50k connections on a single thread with no performance degradation.  asio routines are meant to be run from the same thread as io_service::run();  I think you are hitting a race condition of some sort.

Comment: Hard to tell where the error comes from...  If the listening socket has failed as well, one of the main suspect is dhcp.  The interface's ip address may have changed.  In this case, all open sockets bound to that interface become invalid and must be closed, that includes the listening socket, listening must then be restarted with a new socket.

Comment: I have found that when the error ocurr,   the listen is disappeared.           for example, I use netstat -nat | grep 1234 to show connection,  there is no listen line which line's localAddress is 127.0.0.1:1234 and state is listen. but you can see the line when it run correctly.                                                                                                   but there are some connection which establshed before, some time later, the connection reduce to zero.    I am curios  why the listen is disappeared?  and if I create a new acceptor to listen, do it work??

Answer (score 0):

If the listening socket has failed as well, one of the main suspect is dhcp. The interface's ip address may have changed.

In this case, all open sockets bound to that interface become invalid and must be closed, that includes the listening socket, listening must then be restarted with a new socket.